# Watching LinkedIn Stream Continuously

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to continuously listen to LinkedIn stream watching for users' activity such as adding connection, writing new posts, etc. It's just like watching the Twitter stream to look for certain tweets. How is this possible? Any API? Need help plz. If its paid API, I am ready to have it.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com ?

Comment: There is no help regarding this at [link](developer.linkedin.com).